# wfdb returning JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Basically what I'm trying to do is load The native Python waveform-database package by the following code:

```
import wfdb 

dbs = wfdb.get_dbs()
```

on google colab and this is returning the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1b4589181d89> in <module>()
      1 import wfdb
      2 import json
----> 3 dbs = json.load(wfdb.get_dbs())

3 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

any idea what might be the cause of this?

Comment: What's the output of `print(dbs)`?

Comment: Get a list of all the PhysioNet databases available.

for example:
[
 ['aami-ec13', 'ANSI/AAMI EC13 Test Waveforms'],
 ['adfecgdb', 'Abdominal and Direct Fetal ECG Database'],
 ...
 ['wrist', 'Wrist PPG During Exercise']
]